# Eclipse: "g++ not found in PATH"

Tags: unix, eclipse, g++

Здравствуйте, обращаюсь к вам за помощью, имеется ubuntu 11.10, установленный g++, eclipse CDT. Если я правильно понял, то в PATH нужно указать путь к g++. Опишите подробно, как это сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в свойствах вашего С++ проекта **(Window->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings)** что указан компилятор g++. А в Tool Chain Editor Linux GCC.
Если не поможет, то в Environment (там же) можно добавить свой PATH - Eclipse будет использовать его вместо системного.

Comment: Теперь проблема в том, что все работает, но ошибки все равно вылетают, как можно отключить подсвету синтаксиса в eclipse?И желательно еще убрать авто закрывающиеся "{}" "()".

Comment: Слишком много убрать хотите). Проще было бы поставить Geany, там он по умолчанию цепляется к компилятору и Make файлы тоже не надо создавать. И подсветка, там одной галкой отключается (если мне память не изменяет). Вообще выбор если требуется простая IDE чуть сложнее блокнота с самым минимальным набором инструментов (дебаггер, подсветка и т.п.). В эклипсе все это редактируется, надо только в настройках долго/глубоко ковыряться.

Comment: У меня в бубунте эклипс встал без проблем, все нашел, все подцепил сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Если все ставили из репозиториев, то исполняемый файл должен лежать в директории `/usr/bin`, которая уже находится в `PATH`. Возникли какие-то проблемы? Из коробки g++ в Убунте не установлен.

Comment: /usr/bin/g++. Как можно редактировать PATH?

Comment: Можно и так:

    export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

Но трудно представить причину, почему у Вас /usr/bin отсутствует в PATH. По команде `echo $PATH` Вы увидите содержимое этой переменной.